# Tabs, в кнопке которая открывает контент есть svg, можно делать клик по кнопке, но и так же по svg срабатывает, как убрать клик по svg?

Tags: javascript

При клике раскрыть вкладку, через js присваиваем в тег a, класс tabstovnl--active.
Все вроде ок, но есть иконка в кнопке раскрыть контент и при клике на иконку, добавляется класс не в тег a, а уже в иконку, в этом и глюк, как поправить?

Чтобы нельзя было либо кликать на иконку, ну или если можно но чтобы js присваивал класс к тегу a, а не к тегу иконки, если мы на иконку кликнули.

В примере иконку не видно, я там вместо них вставил слово icon, чтобы эмитировать клик якобы по иконке.

Вообщем кнопка где текст и икона это должно быть одно целое, и при клике на иконку или кнопку в целом, класс присваивает тегу a. ну кнопке, должно так работать.

```js
  window.addEventListener("load", function() {
    const tabstov = document.querySelectorAll(".tabstovnl");
    const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabstovb");

    tabstov.forEach(tab => tab.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();

      let activeTab = document.querySelector(".tabstovnl--active");
      let href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
      let block = document.querySelector(href);

      if (e.target === activeTab) {
        e.target.classList.remove("tabstovnl--active");
        block.classList.remove("tabstovb--active");
      } else {
        tabstov.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("tabstovnl--active"));
        blocks.forEach(block => block.classList.remove("tabstovb--active"));
        e.target.classList.add("tabstovnl--active");
        block.classList.add("tabstovb--active");
      }

    }))
  })
```

```css
.tabstov {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 30px 0 60px -30px;
}
.tabstovnl {
   flex-grow: 1;
   order: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 30px);
    flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 30px);
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #F1F2F5;
border-radius: 3px;
    color: #282725;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
display:block;
}
.tabstovb h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.tabstovnl i::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.tabstovnl:hover {
 border: 1px solid #6FC4C3;
}
.tabstovb ol,
.tabstovb ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.tabstovb ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Скрываем маркеры, отображаемые по умолчанию */
}
.tabstovb ul li::before {
  color: #6FC4C3;
  padding-right: 15px;
  content: "•";
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
}
.tabstovnl--active {
  background: #6FC4C3;
  border: 1px solid #6FC4C3;
  color: #fff;
}
.tabstovnl--active i::before {
  color: #fff;
}
.tabstovb {
  order: 99;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #F1F2F5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.tabstovb--active {
  display: block;
}














html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;}
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}
[hidden]{display:none;}
a{outline:none; text-decoration: none;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;}
sup{top:-0.5em;}
sub{bottom:-0.25em;}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}
button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}
button,input{line-height:normal;}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
input:focus,button:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{outline:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent;}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent;}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent;}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent;}
select{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabstov">
  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab1"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Описание</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab1">
    <h3>Описание</h3>
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab2"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Состав</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab2">
    <h3>Состав</h3>
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab3"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Характеристики</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab3">
   33333
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab4"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Уход за вещами</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab4">
    <h3>Уход за вещами</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Просто сделайте иконки "прозрачными" для действий мыши добавив следующее правило:

```css
.icon-yss1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  const tabstov = document.querySelectorAll(".tabstovnl");
  const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabstovb");

  tabstov.forEach(tab => tab.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    let activeTab = document.querySelector(".tabstovnl--active");
    let href = e.target.getAttribute('href');
    let block = document.querySelector(href);

    if (e.target === activeTab) {
      e.target.classList.remove("tabstovnl--active");
      block.classList.remove("tabstovb--active");
    } else {
      tabstov.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("tabstovnl--active"));
      blocks.forEach(block => block.classList.remove("tabstovb--active"));
      e.target.classList.add("tabstovnl--active");
      block.classList.add("tabstovb--active");
    }

  }))
})
```

```css
.tabstov {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 30px 0 60px -30px;
}

.tabstovnl {
  flex-grow: 1;
  order: 1;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 30px);
  flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 30px);
  margin: 0 0 0 30px;
  padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
  border: 1px solid #F1F2F5;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #282725;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
}

.tabstovb h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}

.tabstovnl i::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.tabstovnl:hover {
  border: 1px solid #6FC4C3;
}

.tabstovb ol,
.tabstovb ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
}

.tabstovb ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Скрываем маркеры, отображаемые по умолчанию */
}

.tabstovb ul li::before {
  color: #6FC4C3;
  padding-right: 15px;
  content: "•";
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
}

.tabstovnl--active {
  background: #6FC4C3;
  border: 1px solid #6FC4C3;
  color: #fff;
}

.tabstovnl--active i::before {
  color: #fff;
}

.tabstovb {
  order: 99;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #F1F2F5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.tabstovb--active {
  display: block;
}

.icon-yss1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}

html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;}
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}
[hidden]{display:none;}
a{outline:none; text-decoration: none;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;}
sup{top:-0.5em;}
sub{bottom:-0.25em;}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}
button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}
button,input{line-height:normal;}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
input:focus,button:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{outline:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent;}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent;}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent;}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent;}
select{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabstov">
  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab1"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Описание</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab1">
    <h3>Описание</h3>
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab2"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Состав</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab2">
    <h3>Состав</h3>
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab3"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Характеристики</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab3">
    33333
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab4"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Уход за вещами</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab4">
    <h3>Уход за вещами</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: кстати, пробовал, не пашет .icon-yss1 {
  pointer-events: none;
}

Comment: а без :before, да все пашет.

Answer (score 0):

Вот еще вариант в js, работает.
Но есть проблема, при клике чет куда-то перекидывает, как пофиксить?

```js
const tabstov = document.querySelectorAll(".tabstovnl");
const blocks = document.querySelectorAll(".tabstovb");

const tabClickHandler = ({ target }) => {
  const targetTab = target.closest('a');
  const block = document.querySelector(`${targetTab.getAttribute('href')}`);
  const isTargetNotActive = !targetTab.classList.contains('tabstovnl--active');

  if (isTargetNotActive) {
    tabstov.forEach(tab => tab.classList.remove("tabstovnl--active"));
    blocks.forEach(block => block.classList.remove("tabstovb--active"));
  }
  
  targetTab.classList.toggle("tabstovnl--active", isTargetNotActive);
  block.classList.toggle("tabstovb--active", isTargetNotActive);
}

tabstov.forEach(tab => tab.addEventListener("click", tabClickHandler));
```

```css
.tabstov {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  margin: 30px 0 60px -30px;
}
.tabstovnl {
   flex-grow: 1;
   order: 1;
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 30px);
    flex: 0 0 calc(25% - 30px);
    margin: 0 0 0 30px;
    padding: 15px 20px 15px 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
border: 1px solid #F1F2F5;
border-radius: 3px;
    color: #282725;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
display:block;
}
.tabstovb h3 {
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
}
.tabstovnl i::before {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.tabstovnl:hover {
 border: 1px solid #6FC4C3;
}
.tabstovb ol,
.tabstovb ul {
  margin-left: 15px;
}
.tabstovb ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  /* Скрываем маркеры, отображаемые по умолчанию */
}
.tabstovb ul li::before {
  color: #6FC4C3;
  padding-right: 15px;
  content: "•";
  font-size: 20px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: -4px;
}
.tabstovnl--active {
  background: #6FC4C3;
  border: 1px solid #6FC4C3;
  color: #fff;
}
.tabstovnl--active i::before {
  color: #fff;
}
.tabstovb {
  order: 99;
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-left: 30px;
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid #F1F2F5;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.tabstovb--active {
  display: block;
}














html,body,div,span,applet,object,iframe,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6,p,blockquote,pre,a,abbr,acronym,address,big,cite,code,del,dfn,em,img,ins,kbd,q,s,samp,small,strike,strong,sub,sup,tt,var,b,u,i,center,dl,dt,dd,ol,ul,li,fieldset,form,label,legend,table,caption,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td,article,aside,canvas,details,embed,figure,figcaption,footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,output,ruby,section,summary,time,mark,audio,video{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;font-size:100%;}
html{-webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;-ms-text-size-adjust:100%;}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,footer,header,hgroup,main,nav,section,summary{display:block;}
audio,canvas,video{display:inline-block;}
audio:not([controls]){display:none;height:0;}
[hidden]{display:none;}
a{outline:none; text-decoration: none;}
abbr[title]{border-bottom:1px dotted;}
pre{white-space:pre;white-space:pre-wrap;word-wrap:break-word;}
sub,sup{font-size:75%;line-height:0;position:relative;}
sup{top:-0.5em;}
sub{bottom:-0.25em;}
fieldset{border:1px solid #c0c0c0;margin:0 2px;padding:.35em .625em .75em;}
button,input,select,textarea{font-family:inherit;font-size:100%;margin:0;}
button,input{line-height:normal;}
button,html input[type="button"],input[type="reset"],input[type="submit"]{-webkit-appearance:button;cursor:pointer;}
button[disabled],input[disabled]{cursor:default;}
input[type="checkbox"],input[type="radio"]{-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box;padding:0;}
input[type="search"]{-webkit-appearance:textfield;-webkit-box-sizing:content-box;box-sizing:content-box;}
input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-cancel-button,input[type="search"]::-webkit-search-decoration{-webkit-appearance:none;}
button::-moz-focus-inner,input::-moz-focus-inner{border:0;padding:0;}
textarea{overflow:auto;vertical-align:top;}
input:focus,button:focus,select:focus,textarea:focus{outline:none;}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {color: transparent;}
:focus::-moz-placeholder          {color: transparent;}
:focus:-moz-placeholder           {color: transparent;}
:focus:-ms-input-placeholder      {color: transparent;}
select{cursor:pointer;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="tabstov">
  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab1"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Описание</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab1">
    <h3>Описание</h3>
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab2"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Состав</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab2">
    <h3>Состав</h3>
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab3"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Характеристики</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab3">
   33333
  </div>

  <a class="tabstovnl" href="#tab4"><i class="icon-yss1">icon</i> Уход за вещами</a>
  <div class="tabstovb" id="tab4">
    <h3>Уход за вещами</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```